# How to change OpenCart2 breadcrumbs home text?

Tags: opencart, breadcrumbs, opencart2.x

I'm struggling with this problem for a few months now and I can't figure out where to change this.
Note that the website I'm working on is coded by someone else, I can't find the part where the fontawesome icon is added to the home text in the breadcrumbs.

Look at the breadcrumbs

[image: breadcrumbs]

As you can see there's an icon added, but I want to add a space between home and the icon, I just can't figure out which file to edit.

If you need any more info, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for `$_['text_home']` in `catalog/language/english/default.php` and add a `space` in it.

Comment: Lol, that was so easy! I already looked in the dutch language files, but never did in the english one.. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Haha if you have `catalog/language/dutch/default.php` existed, then the preferred file would be that one, but I assume you did not had that, so opencart looks for it in English by default.