# How to create breadcrumbs in opencart

Tags: javascript, php, opencart2.3

Actually,i'm using opencart Version 2.3.0.2 and using (so-topdeal) plugin.  when ever i'm using this not showing responsive breadcrumbs it is taking directly like (home:product name),but correct breadcrumbs showing default opencart but i'm using paid module for (so-topdeal) so please post some reference example code.

Comment: could you post some code?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34945365/how-to-change-opencart2-breadcrumbs-home-text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check with the so-topdeal support team if they provide breadcrumbs in their theme. If so there might be enabling/disabling breadcrumb control in the admin end.

or you can paste the following code in the header.tpl or in your custom view file to view the breadcrumb

```
<div class="page-top">
    <div class="container">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>"><?php if($breadcrumb['text'] != '<i class="fa fa-home"></i>') { echo $breadcrumb['text']; } else { if($theme_options->get( 'home_text', $config->get( 'config_language_id' ) ) != '') { echo $theme_options->get( 'home_text', $config->get( 'config_language_id' ) ); } else { echo 'Home'; } } ?></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ol>
    </div><!-- End .container -->
</div>
```